# Inheritance in Spring

Tags: spring, inheritance

I have parent class with a long variable. I do an initialization in the init() method (@PostConstruct) and want to pass a new value into the sub-class. How to do this in Spring?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
@Component
public class Track implements Serializable {

    protected long trackId;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.trackId = sequencesDao.getNext("TRACK_SEQ");
    }
}


@Component("trackPoint")
@Scope("prototype")
public class TrackPoint extends Track implements Serializable, Cloneable {
...
}
```

somewhere in the code:

```
Track trk = context.getBean("track", Track.class);
...
TrackPoint trkpt = (TrackPoint)context.getBean("trackPoint", 
                                    new Object[]{new Double(eElement.getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue()),
                                    new Double(eElement.getAttributes().item(1).getNodeValue()),
                                    0.0,
                                    date});
```

In the debug I see the trackId = 0, but it has to be initialized by sequence value. In other words, trackId <> 0 after the initialization of Track, but it =0 after the initialization of TrackPoint. What is missing?

P.S. Spring 3.2.10.RELEASE

Comment: it seems, like `sequencesDao.getNext("TRACK_SEQ");` returns 0, add code for this class, please and it's missing in `Track` as far as I can see...

Comment: No, it returns a value, I can see it in the Track before the TrackPoint initialization. But TrackPoint's trackId is always 0.

Comment: ...so describe at least the logic, how it works, from what I can see, TrackPoint is singleton, is that what you want?

Comment: Track is a singleton, TrackPoint - prototype. Track is a list of TrackPoint (this is a GPX track).

Comment: When Track is singleton (which is something I cannot imagine how that works, when TrackPoint is prototype), but singleton is initialized just once, which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: Spring is 3.2.10.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created something similar as you have and I have no problem...

### Track

```
package betlista.tests.so.spring;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;

public class Track {

    @Resource
    SequencesDao sequencesDao;

    protected long trackId;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.trackId = sequencesDao.getNext("TRACK_SEQ");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Track(" + hashCode() + "): " + trackId;
    }

}
```

### TrackPoint

```
package betlista.tests.so.spring;


public class TrackPoint extends Track {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TrackPoint(" + hashCode() + "): " + trackId;
    }

}
```

### JavaConfig

```
package betlista.tests.so.spring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {

    @Bean()
    public SequencesDao getSequencesDao() {
        return new SequencesDao();
    }

    @Bean(name="track")
    public Track getTrack() {
        return new Track();
    }

    @Bean(name="trackPoint")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public TrackPoint getTrackPoint() {
        return new TrackPoint();
    }

}
```

### SequencesDao

```
package betlista.tests.so.spring;

public class SequencesDao {

    int cur = 0;

    public int getNext(String s) {
        return cur++;
    }

}
```

### Runner

```
package betlista.tests.so.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = 
                   new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JavaConfig.class);

        Track track1 = ctx.getBean("track", Track.class);
        System.out.println(track1);

        Track track2 = ctx.getBean("track", Track.class);
        System.out.println(track2);

        System.out.println(track1 == track2);

        TrackPoint trackPoint1 = ctx.getBean(TrackPoint.class);
        System.out.println(trackPoint1);

        TrackPoint trackPoint2 = ctx.getBean(TrackPoint.class);
        System.out.println(trackPoint2);

        System.out.println(trackPoint1 == trackPoint2);
    }

}
```

and the output from Runner is as expected

```
Track(1542629621): 0
Track(1542629621): 0
true
TrackPoint(991593213): 1
TrackPoint(1234030171): 2
false
```

just for completeness, my `pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>betlista-tests</groupId>
  <artifactId>so-spring-inheritance</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

So I still see only two options, you DAO is not working well, or TrackPoint is, because of some reason, singleton...

Add similar logging to you code as I have to compare...

Comment: HI Betlista, thank you for your example. I've added the auxiliary TrackSegment between Track and TrackPoint - it inherits trackId from Track as well. BUT - TrackPoint is still with trackId = 0. As you can see in my code, I am creating a bean with several parameters - my investigation shows that Spring does not call the default constructor of the parent (I mean, super() is not calling in the TrackPoint's non-default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved - I've made trackId static and TrackPoint keeps it initialized.

Comment: I do not think, that you want to have `trackId` in `Track` class static. Let's create two `TrackPoint`s and after creation of the second, print `trackId` of both - it will be the same what you do not want I believe...

Comment: No - I definitely need the same trackId for all track points - because they all are in the same physical track. Anyways, I also accept your example as an answer as far as it has pointed me to the right way. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, but consider composition instead of inheritance in your case - `Track` will contain `List<TrackPoint> trackPoints;`...